# Button enabling or disabling when the status for joining is true or false

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want the button "Button_Join" to be enabled when the row "join status" in my table is true and disabled when it's false.

#### Code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterTeam" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
   <td>
     <asp:Button ID="Button_Join" runat="server" Text="Join" Enabled='<%#Enabled() %>'/>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

#### Code behind:

```
protected bool Enabled()
{

    if (Session["join status"] == "False")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I dont know how to do it, but that was my guess, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is this possible instead of all this code behind?

```
<asp:Button ID="Button_Join" runat="server" Text="Join" Enabled='<%#Eval ("join status") %>'/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with your Enabled function

```
Enabled='<%#Eval("Enabled")%>'
```

Comment: I was guessing if i should put that on, i have also suggested it in my question at the bottom of it.

Comment: @Zeuthenjr Did you try it with property?

Comment: Yup, thats the "answer", its the easiest thing to do and it Works.

Comment: @Zeuthenjr Ok, actually I found this answer, I'm not very strong with web foms, I prefer MVC :)

Comment: I don't know what MVC is :)

Comment: Well, i can't get the property to work, i get an error with "get", but   the function is the answer of my question

Answer (score 0):

Set enabled of control in code behind.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     this.Button_Join.Enabled = Session["join status"] != "False";
 }
```

***UPDATE***

Add handler of OnItemDataBound for your repeater

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="myRepeater" OnItemDataBound="myRepeater_ItemDataBound">

protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("Button_Join");
    button.Enabled = Session["join status"] != "False";
}
```

And better put in session bool instead string. You will be able use it this way

```
button.Enabled = (Session["join status"] as bool?) ?? false;
```

Comment: Oh damn, sorry, forgot to say, that the button is in an repeater, damn.. my bad.
I dont know how to call the button when the button is in an repeater

Comment: When i put in that as bool, then it set them all to disabled

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it in the button's load event?

```
protected void Button_Join_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // your logic...
   (sender as Button).Enabled = false;
}
```

EDIT:

If as per your comment the button is in a repeater, use the repeater's `ItemDataBound` event:

```
protected void Your_Repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem ri = e.Item;
    var btn = (ri.FindControl("Button_Join") as Button);
    if (btn != null) btn.Enabled = 
        bool.Parse((Session["join status"] ?? false).ToString()) == true ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the button is in an repeater, is it possible to do it then?

Comment: It puts them all on Disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might have to use `Enabled='<%=Enabled() %>'` instead of  `Enabled='<%#Enabled() %>'`

`<%# %>` used for data binding. I see that you are not binding any data.
`<%= %>` is equivalent of `Response.Write()`

More info [here](http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx)...

Comment: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%=Enabled() %>' for the 'Enabled' property.